# how can iterate and populate the writeFields() arguments, with a hashmap

Tags: java, optimization, junit, hashmap

I have this code, it is a junit test class. I want to come up with a better way to populate writeField() inside the setUP method.

Can i use a hashmap? any examples

```
public class testing {

    @InjectMocks
    private Test test;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IllegalAccessException {

        FieldUtils.writeField(test, "x1", "a", true);
        FieldUtils.writeField(test, "x2", "b", true);
        FieldUtils.writeField(test, "x3", "/c", true);
        FieldUtils.writeField(test, "x4", "d", true);
        FieldUtils.writeField(test, "x5", "e", true);
        FieldUtils.writeField(test, "x6", "f", true);
    }

  
}
```

basically having FieldUtils.writeField inside a for loop and have populate.

Comment: You would still have to enter the same data somewhere be it a Map or a List of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

err, um.. yes?

```
Map<String, String> myStuff = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("subNavLabel", "Marketing");
// ... more map put statements
for (var entry : map.entySet()) {
    FieldUtils.writeField(test, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), true);
}
```

This seems *extremely* first steps java to me, surely this trivial answer isn't what you want, but it answers the question as stated. If it doesn't suffice, consider updating your question or asking a new one with (a lot) more detail.